# Fourier Motzkin elimination with positive coefficients only

Tags: inequality, fourier-motzkin

How can we use Fourier-Motzkin elimination on system of inequalities with positive coefficients preceding each variable $x_1$ to $x_2$. Obviously, in this case we will only have an upper bound as a solution but how do we find it.

For example:

> $5x_1 + 3x_2 \le 8$
>
> $2x_1+5x_2 \le 15$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your two inequalities as
$$x_1 \le \frac{8}{5}- \frac{3}{5}x_2 \quad \textrm{and} \quad x_1 \le \frac{15}{2} -\frac{5}{2}x_2$$
Then
$$x_1 \le \min\{\frac{8}{5}- \frac{3}{5}x_2, \frac{15}{2} -\frac{5}{2}x_2 \}$$
This corresponds to the region of $\mathbb{R}^2$ below the graph of the function
$$x_1 = f(x_2) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{8}{5} - \dfrac{3}{5}x_2 & \mbox{if } x_2 \le \dfrac{59}{19} \\
\dfrac{15}{2}-\dfrac{5}{2}x_2 & \mbox{if } x_2 >\dfrac{59}{19} \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't it be 59/19 for the two cases for x2

Comment: @hacktymh yes, it should be 59/19. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: if we had x1 <= min(a,b,c) where a,b,c are each expressions using (x2 to xn) we how many cases would we have to cover?